# word-break differences in FF&Chrome v.s. IE&Edge

Tags: html, css

The text within a dt-Element is displayed differently. In IE/Edge, the word-wrap: break-word property creates the "wrong" display due to breaking the stirng in a different place than in FF/Chrome.

This is the undesired IE/Edge variant:

[image]

This is the desired Chrome/FF variant:

[image]

Below the html for the section:

```
<dl class="f2f" id="yui_3_17_2_2_1466067872224_80">
  <dt id="yui_3_17_2_2_1466067872224_108">Sitzungsdatum/-uhrzeit</dt>
  <dd>20. Oktober 2017, 10:00 - 14:00 Europa/Berlin</dd>

  <!-- more content of the same structure -->
</dl>
```

And here is the relevant css:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px)
@media screen and (min-width: 500px)
.f2f dt {
    clear: left;
    float: left;
    text-align: right;
    width: 23%;
}
.f2f dt {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

I have tried using white-space and word-break properties to fix this, but to no avail yet.

Thanks for any help you can give me on this :)

*edited for html and css content

Comment: Could you post the HTML for this?

Comment: Edited the original post.

Comment: Are you sure you test it in samesized windows?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. The faulty word-break occurs as long as the dt and dd elements are next to each other in IE/Edge.

Comment: I can't get it to display the way it is on your screenshots, probably missing more CSS. Anyway, 2 things that come to mind: (1) `padding-right: n px`  to push the remaining "-uh" to the next line. (2) have you tried adding a space between "-" and "uhrzeit"?

Comment: To your first idea, how would i specify that to onlyhappen in IE/Edge? to Nr. 2), yes i did and curiously it changed nothing...

Comment: Just a follow-up question since no solution has been upcomming up to now: Are there other ways to influence this asides from white-space, word-break, or word-wrap ?